# Ocultar div em páginas especificas com jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

Bom dia,

Estou com um problema para ocultar uma div apenas em uma página especificas, no caso tem um arquivo php com include_once que inclui nas páginas o header, mas tem uma página especifica que não precisa de uma div que está dentro do header e quero ocultar, como poderia fazer isso com jquery.

Comment: Você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Poste o código por favor... Teoricamente, você poderia buscar por ID, Class, etc. Mas cada caso é um caso. Poste o código...

Comment: Enviar uma div desnecessariamente via PHP para depois ocultar em JS parece realmente estranho (leia-se gambiarra). Não seria mais sensato determinar isso no servidor mesmo? Ou teria alguma justificativa real para isso, para entendermos melhor?

Comment: Gambiarra por Gambiarra... porque só na página que vc não quer a div vc não coloca na `<head>` um `<style>` com display:none na #suadiv. Assim nem precisa de jQuery...

Comment: Mais fácil seria no include colocar IF caminho!=tal { <html da div> } em php mesmo

Comment: Eu costumo dar nomes às páginas, colocando no início, antes da tag <html>: `$pagename = "home";`... assim fica fácil exibir ou ocultar um conteúdo específico de acordo com a variável `$pagename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  if (window.location.pathname == "meusite/url1php"||window.location.pathname == "meusite/diretorio/url2.html"||window.location.pathname == "url3.html") {
        $('#umadiv').hide();
  } else {
        $('#umadiv').show();
  }
});
```

**Sem script**

Você também pode definir uma classe no elemento `<body>` indicando a página atual. Então, se você está na página de índice, `<body class='index'>` você pode usar CSS para ocultar elementos específicos.

```
body.index #umadiv { display: none; }
```

Exemplo:

```css
body.index #umadiv { display: none; };
```

```html
<body class='index'>

<div id="umadiv">
kkkkkkk
</div>
Conteudo da pagina
</body>
```

Você também pode usar o seguinte esquema:

**index.php**

```
  <php
    $pagina="index";
    .......
    include_once "header.php";
    .......
```

**pagina1.php**

```
  <php
    $pagina="pagina1";
    .......
    include_once "header.php";
    .......
```

**pagina2.php**

```
  <php
    $pagina="pagina2";
    .......
    include_once "header.php";
    .......
```

**etc.....**

**header.php**

```
  $ocultar = array("index", "pagina1", "pagina2"); 
  if (!in_array($pagina, $ocultar)) { 

      //a div aqui

  }
```